# How can i put the element RecyclerView under the element Toolbar in the Android Layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

Hey i want in my android app that the recyclerlistview and the floatingActionButton not cut the toolbar. Here is my Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar_task_layout">
            </include>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_task"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerView_task">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton_task_openDialog_"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerView_task"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here you can see the problem:

[image]

**Update:**

Here is the toolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:id="@+id/toolbar_task"
                                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                                   android:elevation="6dp"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                                   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0 items selected"
            android:id="@+id/counter_task"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: share Toolbar_task_layout file

Comment: see update :) ...

Comment: use `layout_below` in `recyclerview` and give the `id` of `toolbar_task_layout`.

Comment: i dont can use layout_below ;(

Comment: Let increase your `margin_top` value and test. I think recyclerview start within from toolbar.

Comment: this dont work ...nothing changed

Comment: @Tarasov just create new project from Android studio with existing template that contains fab button. You can quickly see and adjust ur need.

Comment: ok i do this ......

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_task_layout"></include>`

with this:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_task_layout" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

EDIT: I assume you also want your FAB to be on the bottom right since this is the norm, try setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in your FAB and make the RecyclerViews height match_parent

Comment: the toolbar layout shouldn't really matter, did you try the fix already?

Comment: Ahh i see why now, you are using a coordinator layout, that's my bad for not noticing, doesn't it work to just set layout_below in the include to the id of the recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

try this make your `toolbar` **android:layout_height**  to `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/ac_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_task_layout"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerView_task"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_task"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton_task_openDialog_"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerView_task"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope this will help.....